# Ionic inner-tabs routing

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

When you create the basic Tabs project in ionic, you get tabs, "Status", "Chats", "Friends", "Account", and "Badges". Now, if I want to add a link on the Dashboard-Status view that routes me to a sub nav under the Friends tab, I can do that using the following:

```
<a ui-sref='tab.friend-detail'>
```

However, if I do that, I lose the back arrow that I would normally get if I navigate to the same view using the Friends tab. The work-around I use is to create a sub nav for "Home" that uses the same controller and view. Like this:

```
  .state('tab.home-friend-detail', {
  url: 'home/friend/:friendId',
  views: {
    'tab-friends': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/friend-detail.html',
      controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

and point to that state in the link. Is there a way to get to a sub-nav state from any view and maintain the back button/arrow that gets me back to the parent state? If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Hmm why would you want to do that? When you go to friend-detail you pass along the id of the selected friend in friends. Which "id" do you want to visit when you click on the link in your status-view ?

Comment: @novalain It was just an example. For, the sake of argument, let's say I had a link on the "home" view that links to Friend #3 details. My question is more broad as to how to accomplish what I want without the duplicated route workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to keep the back button when you go directly to a nested-view state since the tabs keep their own stack of history seperately.

You could however go back to the parent state for any view by using `$ionicHistory` and call `$ionicHistory.goBack();` in your controller. This means however that you will have to create a custom back-button in your friend-detail page.

Comment: I was afraid of that, unfortunately. I don't think we use the tabs routing as they were intended, but that's not my call.